# Why does "fix" take so much memory?

Tags: haskell, memory

I used this code:

```
fix' f = let x = f x in x
```

And then ran

```
> :set +s
> fix' (const 'u')
```

Only to get:

```
'u'
(0.00 secs, 83,512 bytes)
```

Now why does this take so much memory?

I'd evaluate it as follows:

```
fix' f = let x = f x in x
fix' (const 'u')
let x = const 'u' x in x
const _ x = x
const 'u' undefined
'u'
```

This is of course a grossly inefficient format, but only takes 105 bytes in ASCII encoding, plus maybe a bit of memory usage for comparison still wouldn't get to the usage in the `fix` example.

Comment: In GHCi, `'u'` alone will already consume some KBs, since it stands for `putStrLn (show 'u')`, everything is interpreted (unlike in GHC) and no optimization is attempted.

Comment: Test against just `'u'` alone and compare the memory, to see if `fix` is the real problem,